# Java - Sending OpenCv Mat Object from android to PC through s TCP connection

Tags: java, android, opencv, tcp, mat

I am trying to send Opencv Mat object from my android device to my server(PC).

Now, I am using the following code to convert the mat object to byte array and send to my server.

```
public void send (final Mat mat) {
    new Thread( "Send Thread"){
        public void run(){
            try{
                if (socket!=null ){
                    DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    byte[] byte_array = new byte[(int) (mat.total() * mat.channels())];
                    mat.get(0, 0, byte_array);

                    int size = byte_array.length;
                    int width = (int)mat.size().width;
                    int height = (int)mat.size().height;
                    dOut.writeLong(size);
                    dOut.writeInt(width);
                    dOut.writeInt(height);
                    dOut.write(byte_array);
                    dOut.flush();
                }
            } catch( Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

And receice the data via the following code

```
public void receiveTCP() throws IOException {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            BufferedReader br = null;
            DataInputStream dis = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(receiveSocket.getInputStream()));
                dis = new DataInputStream(receiveSocket.getInputStream());

                while(true){

                    int size = dis.readInt();
                    int width = dis.readInt();
                    int height = dis.readInt();
                        imageByteArray = new byte[(int) size];
                         dis.readFully(imageByteArray, 0, size);

                        Mat mat = convertByteArrayToMat(imageByteArray, width, height);
                        try {Highgui.imwrite(System.currentTimeMillis()+".png",mat);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        imageByteArray = null;

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }.start();

}

public static Mat convertByteArrayToMat(byte[] imageByteArray, int width, int height) {
    Mat mat = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mat.put(0, 0, imageByteArray);
    return mat;
}
```

However, the image is invalid.

What is the correct way to send the mat object via TCP?

Comment: My mistake. I have corrected it but still the image is invalid/

Comment: How did you solve this?